# How can I derive monotonically increasing polynomial functions with steep curves from [0,1] to [0,1]?

Tags: polynomials

For computer graphics reasons, I need a Taylor polynomial function on the interval [0,1] like the classic smoothstep function 3x^2-2x^3 which outputs a monotonically increasing value on the interval [0, 1] but that has a much steeper curve. It should have only one inflection point (not counting the beginning or the ends.) The beginning should be convex and the end should be concave.

I would also like to be able to tweak the function to my needs and make it steeper or not so steep with some parameters if possible.

How can I derive steep polynomial functions from [0,1] to [0,1]?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with a spline instead?

Answer (score 1):

"Taylor series" is the wrong terminology to use.

What you're probably
looking for is a polynomial satisfying some properties. Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_{k}x^{k}$.
We need to satisfy:
\begin{align*}
f(0) & =0;\\
f(1) & =1;\\
f^{\prime}(x) & =\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}kx^{k-1}\geq0 & \text{for }0\leq x\leq1.
\end{align*}
The first two equations are self-explanatory. The third ensures that
the polynomial is nondecreasing. Save from the degenerate case of
a line ($f(x)=x$), you should have enough freedom to fool around
with the first derivative to get "steeper" functions.

For example, if $k=2$, then you'll find that the only polynomials
that satisfy the above are $cx+(1-c)x^{2}$ parameterized by $0\leq c\leq2$.
The parameter $c$ can be used to control the steepness:

[image]

Another example are the polynomials
$x^k$ and $1-(1-x)^k$.
These also satisfy the above. The larger the value of $k$,
the steeper the result:

[image]
[image]

However, you might not want to use high degree polynomials as these are more expensive (in terms of floating point operations) to compute.

Answer (score 0):

I want a polynomial, probably low-degree.

So let's try `a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + e^4`.

I want the point at zero to be zero so a must be zero.

I want the point at one to be one so c + d + e must be one.

I want the start to be convex and curve up so the first derivative at zero must be zero and hence b must be zero.

I want the end to be concave and curve down so the first derivative at one must be zero and hence 2c + 3d + 4e = 0.

Then d = 4 - 2 c and e = 1 - (c + d) and c is left free.

I am unsure of how to determine if c is two low or too high. I know that values lower than -1 don't work and values higher than around 7 don't work but I don't know why.

Comment: You also want only one inflection point, so you need $12ex^2+6dx+2c$ to have only one root in $[0,1]$. This creates an inequality constraint on $c$.

Comment: @Ian So, this is why sometimes c can be too low or high? That makes sense. Is there a way to calculate the valid bounds for c?

Comment: Sure, it's just tedious: plug in $d=4-2c,e=-3+c$, and set up the quadratic formula.